# Three tables join and count showing wrong result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables and I need to get all info from catalog ,join ratings table and join to comments table and  then count comments by catalog posts, my SQL query:

```
SELECT
    catalog.catalog_id,
    catalog.slug,
    catalog.title,
    catalog.city,
    catalog.street,
    catalog.image COUNT(ratings.rate) AS votes,
    COUNT(comments.catalog_id) AS total_comments,
    ROUND(SUM(ratings.rate) / COUNT(ratings.rate)) AS average
FROM
    catalog
LEFT JOIN ratings ON ratings.object_id = catalog.catalog_id
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.catalog_id = catalog.catalog_id
GROUP BY
    catalog.catalog_id
ORDER BY
    average,
    votes DESC
```

Everything shows fine only total_comments bad numbers 6, but in comments table only 2 rows, so its bad result. I'm thinking it's a problem with the grouping. I've tried adding `GROUP BY catalog.catalog_id, comments.catalog_id` but it didn't help.
My tables:

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: What is the question? Ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have multiple ratings and comments, so you are getting a cartesian product for each post.

The correct solution is to pre-aggregate the data before joining.

```
SELECT c.*, r.votes, c.total_comments,
       ROUND(sumrate / votes) AS average
FROM catalog c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.object_id, COUNT(*) as votes, SUM(r.rate) as sumrate
      FROM ratings r
      GROUP BY r.object_id
     ) r
     ON r.object_id = c.catalog_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.catalog_id, COUNT(*) as total_comments
      FROM comments c
      GROUP BY c.catalog_id
     ) c
     ON c.catalog_id = c.catalog_id
GROUP BY c.catalog_id
ORDER BY average, votes DESC;
```